# Another way instead of do-until loop to make code execute faster

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I need help on how to make my code execute faster. I have a very large volume of data and my '`Do Until loop`' causes the slow execution. I wonder if there's a way to make my code run faster. I only used do until loop because I'm comfortable with it. Thanks

```
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim last As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As String, y As String

Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = WB1.Worksheets("Source")

last = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row

i = 2
Do Until Sheets("Source").Cells(i, 1) = ""
    x = Left(Sheets("Source").Cells(i, 6), 3)
    y = Left(Sheets("Source").Cells(i, 23), 7)
    If x = "611" Or y = "INITIAL" Then

        Sheets("Source").Cells(i, 25) = "INITIAL"

    Else

        ws1.Range("Y2:Y" & last).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A:A,'Assignment Reference'!$C:$E,3,FALSE)"

    End If

    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Why are you repopulating an entire column of formulas inside your loop?

Comment: I need to repopulate the entire column using vlookup formula but I must first determine specific values before inserting the formula on the entire row.

Comment: But you're putting the **same** formula into the **same** cells repeatedly. That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Yes, the formula is intended to the entire column but not for some cells which has a value "611" or "Initial" If the cell has a value of "Initial" then the formula won't be applied to it.

Comment: No, that's not what your code does. It puts the same formula into all the same cells each time. I think you should be using: `ws1.Range("Y" & i).Formula`

Comment: Ok I'll try that. But my code gives the correct data. But I would still try your idea. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Rory, It also works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible way how to improve the performance of Excel's VBA code. At best you read some articles about that:

- [Excel VBA performance coding best practices](https://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/)
- [Optimizing VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm)

---

Edit:
As suggested by *Bond* I here is what I do in my VBA code to improve the execution performance:

```
Option Explicit

Dim screenUpdating As Boolean
Dim calculation As XlCalculation
Dim enableEvents As Boolean
Dim displayPageBreaks As Boolean



' Freezes Excel into its current state to improve
' performance during executing macro code. Be sure
' to call DoEvents occasionally during execution to
' prevent completly freezing the Excel window.
' Call this routine before all other code but after
' setting up proper exception handling.
Public Sub freezeSystem()
    'Save Excel configuration to reset later
    screenUpdating = Application.screenUpdating
    calculation = Application.calculation
    enableEvents = Application.enableEvents
    displayPageBreaks = ActiveSheet.displayPageBreaks

    'Turn off some Excel functionality so your code runs faster
    Application.screenUpdating = False
    Application.calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.enableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.displayPageBreaks = False 'Note this is a sheet-level setting, but only necessary for ActiveSheet if code do not change the ActiveSheet
End Sub




' Unfreezes Excel and resets it into the configuration it had
' before the freezeSystem() was executed.
' Call this routine at the end of the macro code and also during
' the cleanup of exception handling.
Public Sub defreezeSystem()
    ' Reset Excel configuration into previous state
    Application.screenUpdating = screenUpdating
    Application.calculation = calculation
    Application.enableEvents = enableEvents
    ActiveSheet.displayPageBreaks = displayPageBreaks 'Note this is a sheet-level setting, but only necessary for ActiveSheet if code do not change the ActiveSheet

    ' Perform recalculation of all formulas
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
End Sub




' This routine is intended to update the Excel window
' while executing macro code in controlled manner if
' necessary. Be aware that calling this function too
' often will drastically reduce the execution performance.
Public Sub updateSystem()
    If Application.screenUpdating = False Then
        Application.screenUpdating = True
        Application.CalculateFullRebuild
        Application.screenUpdating = False
    Else
        Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    End If
End Sub
```

Call `freezeSystem()` at the beginning or your code to improve the performance during execution. Call `defreezeSystem()`at the end of your code and while cleaning up during exception handling if necessary.

I do it in this way:

```
Sub entryPoint()
    On Error GoTo entryPointErrorHandler    ' set up exception handling
    freezeSystem
    [your regular code goes here]

entryPointCleanUp:                          ' clean up from exception and normal operation
    [your cleanup code goes here]
    defreezeSystem
    Exit Sub

entryPointErrorHandler:                     ' exception handling
    [your exception handling code goes here]
    GoTo entryPointCleanUp                  ' jump to clean up code

End Sub
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Bond your are right. I now added some code example.

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed things up is to tell Excel not to bother with updating the screen or calculating cells. Turn these off before the loop and turn them on after:

```
'***** Before loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'***** After loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: These are certainly good options for speeding up macros in general, but this doesn't specifically address the performance issue with this question.

Comment: It's also a good idea to capture the current value of `Application.Calculation` at the start of the code and restore it at the end.

Comment: @Enigmativity I agree, but sometimes just stopping Excel from doing unnecessary things will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the references you already set. E.g: instead of

```
Do Until Sheets("Source").Cells(i, 1) = ""
x = Left(Sheets("Source").Cells(i, 6), 3)
y = Left(Sheets("Source").Cells(i, 23), 7)
```

use

```
Do Until Sheets("Source").Cells(i, 1) = ""
   x = Left(ws1.Cells(i, 6), 3)
   y = Left(ws1.Cells(i, 23), 7)
```

I would also try to avoid `VLOOKUP`, which is very slow. If all you need is to check for the existence a a value in a range, `COUNTIF` is much faster.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `MATCH` instead of `COUNTIF`? The latter will presumably need to "look at" all the cells in the range but I imagine the `MATCH` function quits once it has found a matching entry.

Comment: @ChipsLetten: interesting idea, worth to be validated with a large dataset.